# Why is $\left|\mbox{det}\mathrm{D}F\right|=\frac{1}{\left|\left(\mbox{det}(\mathrm{D}F^{-1})\right)\circ F\right|}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, determinant

[These notes](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~stein/lehre/SoSem09/distrvo.pdf) I'm reading say (page 72 on the paper, 76 on the PDF, just before the equation marked with a star)

> Noting that $\left|\mbox{det}\mathrm{D}F\right|=\frac{1}{\left|\left(\mbox{det}(\mathrm{D}F^{-1})\right)\circ F\right|}$ and $\mbox{det}\mathrm{D}(F^{-1})=\partial_{1} f$

I don't understand why the equality holds. But first, I'll explain what everything means.

We have a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.

$F^{-1}$ is an $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which maps $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ to $(f(\mathbf{x}),x_2,\dots,x_n)$.

I understand the second equality in the highlighted text:

$$\mathrm{D}(F^{-1})=\begin{vmatrix}
\partial_{x_1}f(\mathbf{x}) &\partial_{x_2}f(\mathbf{x}) &\dots &\partial_{x_n}f(\mathbf{x})\\
\partial_{x_1} x_2 &\partial_{x_2}x_2 & &\partial_{x_n}x_2\\
\vdots  & & &\vdots\\
\partial_{x_1} x_n &\partial_{x_2}x_n & &\partial_{x_n}x_n\\
\end{vmatrix} =\begin{vmatrix}
\partial_{x_1}f(\mathbf{x}) &\partial_{x_2}f(\mathbf{x}) &\dots &\partial_{x_n}f(\mathbf{x})\\
0 &1 & &0\\
\vdots  & &\ddots  &\vdots\\
0 &0 & &1\\
\end{vmatrix}$$
and so its determinant is just gonna be $\partial_1 f$.

However, I can't see where the first one comes from.

Comment: What does the denominator mean?

Comment: Absolute value of ((the determinant of the Jacobian of $F^{-1}$) composed with $F$)

Comment: This looks very similar to the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) says that:
$$
J_{F^{-1}}(F(p)) = [J_F(p)]^{-1}
$$
where the right hand side is the matrix inverse, $p$ is some point, $J$ is the jacobian, and $F$ is your function.
We can multiply through by $J_F(p)$ to get that:
$$
J_F(p)J_{F^{-1}}(F(p)) = I
$$
where the right hand side is the identity matrix.
Taking the determinant, and remembering that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$, we get that:
$$
\det(J_F(p))\det(J_{F^{-1}}(F(p))) = 1
$$
We can then divide through by the right part of the product, to get:
$$
\det(J_F(p)) = \frac{1}{\det(J_{F^{-1}}(F(p)))}
$$
which I believe is just different notation for what you've written.

Comment: The equation is true with or without absolute values.  Your derivation is correct.